# convert string date to date type in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, date

In a school website, I want to enable the admin to filter students based on date range when they were born. Dates in my tblStudent are stored as strings, so I cannot use:

```
SELECT ts.Name from tblStudent ts WHERE ts.BirthDay>'1367/01/31' AND ts.BirthDay<'1377/01/31'
```

I have saved dates (Jalali Format) in database table tblStudent. I need to do comparison based on dates. So I need to convert date strings to date type in sql server. To this purpose I used:

```
SELECT convert(date,tblStudent.BirthDay) from tblStudent
```

However,It stops after 27 results with the following error

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have the following date strings in my tblStudent table.

```
1379/09/01
1375/04/20
1378/03/02
1378/03/21
1378/04/18
1378/04/18
1378/05/05
1375/04/20
1379/01/03
1378/03/01
1370/09/09
1378/03/22
1375/09/15
1379/09/01
1379/09/10
1375/04/08
1375/05/06
1370/09/09
1379/10/10
1375/04/10
1375/11/01
1375/04/04
1375/08/11
1375/05/05
1376/09/19
1375/12/12
1376/01/13
1375/15/10
1375/04/14
1375/04/04
1375/05/14
1374/11/11
1375/05/30
1375/05/14
1377/12/13
1377/02/31
1377/12/14
1377/01/13
1375/05/31
1377/11/05
1377/07/05
1375/05/31
1377/03/01
1377/04/01
1377/05/02
1377/05/04
1377/03/03
1377/01/14
1377/05/30
1377/04/31
1375/05/30
1376/06/12
1375/12/10
1377/08/14
1377/03/04
1375/04/08
1375/07/18
1375/08/09
1375/09/12
1375/11/12
1376/12/12
1375/01/02
1375/05/09
1375/04/09
1376/01/01
1375/01/30
1377/04/04
1375/05/23
1375/05/01
1377/02/01
1367/12/05
1375/05/31
1373/03/29
1373/03/03
1375/05/05
```

Is there a way to convert these string dates to date type and then compare them with some query? For example, such a query can be:

```
SELECT ts.Name from tblStudent ts where ts.BirthDay>'1375/05/31'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make them ints and compare them:

```
SELECT ts.Name 
FROM   tblStudent ts 
WHERE  CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(ts.BirthDay,'/','') > 13670131 
       AND CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(ts.BirthDay,'/','') < 13770131
```

Or for your second example:

```
SELECT ts.Name 
FROM   tblStudent ts 
WHERE  CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(ts.BirthDay,'/','') > 13750531
```

This would work because having the order Year-Month-Day will ensure that the int representation of a later time will be greater than the int representation of an earlier time.

I really do not know if this is the best idea, but it is an idea of how to do it. After all you would be using a conversion.

From C# you have a few options:

1. If your input is string:

   ```
   var dateInt = Int32.Parse(dateString.Replace("/",""));
   ```
2. If your input is Date then:

   ```
   var dateInt = Int32.Parse(dateValue.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
   ```
3. You could also pass the string itself in the db and let the db do the work for you :

   ```
   DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR(10) 
   SET @Date = ...--This will be filled with the inputed string
   DECLARE @DateINT AS INT 
   SET @DateINT = CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(@Date,"/",""))
   ```

Comment: Cool, this works for data in the database. I wonder what C# function I can use to convert user-entered 'yyyy/mm/dd' date format to yyyymmdd int